# Client evaluation in top-level EF Core projection

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

Suppose I perform a query and project into an anonymous type; that would perform evaluation on the server:

```cs
var people = await context
  .People
  .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
  .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Surname, x.Forename })
  .ToListAsync();
```

But suppose I perform a query and need to project into a concrete type.

Option 1: map results into concrete type:

```cs
var people = (await context
  .People
  .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
  .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Surname, x.Forename })
  .ToListAsync())
  .Select(x => new PersonDto(x.Id, x.Surname, x.Forename));
```

Option 2: use concrete type in *"top-level projection"*:

```cs
var people = await context
  .People
  .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
  .Select(x => new PersonDto(x.Id, x.Surname, x.Forename));
  .ToListAsync()
```

About (2), [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation-in-the-top-level-projection) state that in a top-level projection, some evaluation is performed in the database and some on the client. (But the docs show an example of a client function in an anonymous type, so it differs to my use case.)

In this specific example, am I right in assuming that **all evaluation is performed on the server**, and that (2) is just a short-cut for (1), i.e. they are functionally equivalent?

Comment: I'm unsure about EFCore 7, but ever since EF1.0 back in 2008 the query-translator never supported using non-default constructors for result-types: you always had to post object-initializer lists _or_ anonymous-types, but it _did_ support query-projection on the server such that it only did a `SELECT` for the actual data pulled-in by the object-initializer list or anonymous-type. If you're finding that Option 2 works (i.e. your actual `SELECT` query is optimal) then I guess EFCore7 now finally supports ctors (finally!)

Comment: UPDATE: Woo! Looks like EFCore does support using ctors in query projections: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors

Comment: @Dai I thought that was when binding the fetched data to objects (they added that to make DDD-like code more convenient, where there is a private ctor for EF and parameterised ctor for client code, which enforces validation). But I wonder whether that also applies to using the ctor *in a projection*?

Comment: Well, have you tried your example queries against a real database and looked at the SQL it generates?

Comment: @Dai I'll need to do that. I also asked for clarification in [the docs](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/4551).

Comment: @Dai It seems to fetch only the fields I've specified!

Comment: Yes, you are right. It top-level projection, EF is trying to translate everything to SQL (arguments, assignments). If it is not possible, part of projection can be evaluated one the client side. There are no difference between anonymous classes and DTO classes. So (2) variant is the right choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question:

*all evaluation is performed on the server, and that (2) is just a short-cut for (1), i.e. they are functionally equivalent?*

### Answer

Obviously, the `PersonDto` object is instantiated on client side, but, EF is able to get the three constructor parameters values, `x.Id, x.Surname, x.Forename` from the database. Just this 3 values ( `Select id, surname, forename from people order by name` ):

> EF Core supports partial client evaluation in the top-level projection (essentially, the last call to Select()). If the top-level projection in the query can't be translated to the server, EF Core will fetch any required data from the server and evaluate remaining parts of the query on the client. If EF Core detects an expression, in any place other than the top-level projection, which can't be translated to the server, then it throws a runtime exception

Full explanation at `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval` docs.

### Test

Here a sample of EF translating top-level projection to SQL. Expression:

```cs
var result = 
    dbcontext.
    Customers.
    Select(x => new PersonName2CharsDto(x.Name.Substring(0,2))).
    ToList();
```

The generated sql (for sqlite):

```sql
SELECT substr("c"."Name", 0 + 1, 2)
FROM "Customers" AS "c"
```